# Get array of objects then display it in my component

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular

I tried to show an array of Objects.

This is how I get in my component

```
getFiles(){
    this.fileService.getFileList().subscribe(res => {
      this.files = res;
      console.log(this.files);
    })
}
```

In my service

```
getFileList() {
 return this.http.get(`http://localhost:4001/files`)
}
```

the output from this.files is:

```
> {secret: Array(2)} secret: Array(2) 0: files: (2) ["file1.pdf",
> "file2.pdf"]
> __proto__: Object 1: {pass: "88VpGQAtNB"} length: 2
> __proto__: Array(0)
> __proto__: Object
```

JSON.stringify gaves me output

```
stringify gave me {"secret":[{"files":["46544556_2.pdf","org_46544556_2.pdf"]},{"pass":"hoc1WpNj63"}]}
```

How Can I iterate through this array of objects?

```
<li *ngFor="let file of files" >
{{file}}
</li
```

This gaves me error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]'
>   of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as
>   Arrays.

There is my backend

```
app.get('/files', function (req, res) {
  let folder = app.get('filePath');
  const filesInDir = fs.readdirSync(folder, {
      withFileTypes: true
    })
    .filter(item => !item.isDirectory())
    .map(item => item.name)
  res.send({
    secret: [{ files: filesInDir }, { pass: password }],
  })

  return console.log('files from tmp dir: ' + filesInDir)
});
```

Comment: The error message clearly says that you response is not an array. Can you try `console.log(JOSN.stringify(this.files))` and post the same here with your question.

Comment: @Manish stringify gave me {"secret":[{"files":["46544556_2.pdf","org_46544556_2.pdf"]},{"pass":"hoc1WpNj63"}]}

Comment: as you can the the way your response is structured accordingly the update your `this.files` should be assigned like this `this.files = res.secret[0].files`. Try this out it will solve your problem.

Comment: @Manish still error: Property 'secret' does not exist on type 'Object'

Comment: Will it be possible for you to create a reproducible demo of the error on stackblitz. Will be able to help better

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the files array in the `this.files` object.
The error you're getting is because you are using and object `this.files` in `*ngFor`, instead you need to use the files property inside the object which is a list so changing your html as following will work.

```
<ul *ngIf="files">
    <li *ngFor="let file of files.secret.files" >
</ul>
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

or better approach is you declare a variable

```
this.files =[];
```

and then you do the following:

```
 getFiles(){
    this.fileService.getFileList().subscribe(res => {
      this.files = res.secret.files; // get files from res
      console.log(this.files);
    })
    }
```

and in your html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let file of files" >
</ul>
```

Comment: Got erro: FileListComponent.html:4 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as updateDirectives]

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki that's because the html is being rendered before the api returns any response just add an `*ngIf="files"` on the container. I have updated  my answer check it out

Comment: no errors but still nothing. I did JSON.stringify and here's output  {"secret":[{"files":["46544556_2.pdf","org_46544556_2.pdf"]},{"pass":"hoc1WpNj63"}]}

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki there's no need to do JSON.stringify. and I missed that your files array is inside secret property so I have updated my answer. in the second solution you dont need an `*ngIf` as well

Comment: I tried something like this but I have no idea why Property 'secret' does not exist on type 'Object'.. it is! hmm

Comment: @MarcinDomorozki Strange. you should create a plunkr

Comment: I'll create in an hour

Comment: I did it chceck answer. 
if you want please edit your answer and I'll accept it

Answer (score 0):

```
 getFiles(){
    this.fileService.getFileList().subscribe(res => {
      this.files = res.files; // get files from res
      console.log(this.files);
    })
    }
```

you need to change the method in the component.

Comment: Got errorL Property 'files' does not exist on type 'Object'

Answer (score 0):

You are returning an array in your response. So you need to use something like

```
if (res.secret[0].files) {
   this.files = res.secret[0].files;
}
```

or you can change your response coming from the Server.

```
res.send({
secret: {
         files: [filesInDir],
         pass: [password]
        },
})
```

and then do

```
this.files = res.secret.files;
```

Comment: I tried second solutions but: Property 'secret' does not exist on type 'Object'.

Answer (score 0):

**CAUTION**: Use this approach only if your response object isn't huge.

**ts file**

```
  objKeys = Object.keys; //reference to be used in template
  arrJSON = '{"secret":[{"files":["46544556_2.pdf","org_46544556_2.pdf"]},{"pass":"hoc1WpNj63"}]}';
  arrObj = JSON.parse(this.arrJSON);
```

**html**

```
<div *ngFor="let key of objKeys(arrObj)">
  <div *ngFor="let secretKeyObj of arrObj[key]">
    <div *ngFor="let secKey of objKeys(secretKeyObj)">
      <div *ngIf="secKey === 'files'">
        <p *ngFor="let file of secretKeyObj[secKey]">{{ file }}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it base on @Jazib answer.

The correct way is:

```
 getFiles() {
    this.fileService.getFileList().subscribe(res => {
      this.files = res;
      this.test = this.files.secret.files
      console.log(this.files.secret.files);
    })
  }
```

and html

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let file of test" >
</ul>
```